# How can i fix the error 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView must not be null'

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerView where I send data with my adapter but got the error

> `RecyclerView must not be null`

code with my adpater:

```
class InWaitingFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var adapter: FastItemAdapter<BarterWaitingItem>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {

        println("CONTAINER:  " + container)

        val inflate: FrameLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_in_waiting, container, false) as FrameLayout

        adapter = FastItemAdapter<BarterWaitingItem>()

       waitingRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

       waitingRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.93.182.95:8888")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(RequestManager::class.java)

        val action  = service.getPending()


        action.enqueue(object: Callback<ArrayList<GetBarterResponse>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ArrayList<GetBarterResponse>>,
                response: Response<ArrayList<GetBarterResponse>>
            ) {
                val allBarter = response.body()
                if(allBarter != null){
                    for (c in allBarter){
                        println("OBJET: ${c.buyer_object.title}")
                    }

                    println("ONRESPONSE En attente: " + response.body().toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<GetBarterResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
                println("ONFAILURE En attente: " + t.toString())
            }
        })

        return inflate
    }


}
```

got an error to on the this of `LinearLayoutManager(this)`, says:

> ```
> `require:Context!
>  Founds: InWaitingFragment
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `LinearLayoutManager(this)` to `LinearLayoutManager(this.context)`

Answer (score 1):

For your LinearLayoutManager, Fragments aren't extending Context so you cant use `this` as parameters. Instead, use this:

```
waitingRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!)
```

For the runtime error, "RecyclerView must not be null", it's because you're accessing the properties of the `waitingRecyclerView` inside the `onCreateView` callback. The layout hasn't been initialized yet. You can move your initialization of `waitingRecyclerView` to the 'onViewCreated' callback.

If you must initialize the `waitingRecyclerView` inside `onCreateView` you can access the `waitingRecyclerView` via the object you created when inflating the layout, i.e. `inflate`:

```
inflate.waitingRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!)
inflate.waitingRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
```